# How to sort nested hashmaps using values from Inner map and outer map in Java8?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, hashmap, comparator

In my code

```
Map<Map<String,Date>,Integer> businessCountMap = new HashMap<>();
```

> ```
>  Eg: {{59087=2/7/2021}=5,{59087=1/31/2021}=6,{59087=1/31/2021}=8,{63771=2/7/2021}=6}
> ```

I have a map like above. I need to  sort descending the entries by both Date and Integer and return like this

> ```
> {{63771=2/7/2021}=6,{59087=2/7/2021}=5,{59087=1/31/2021}=8,{59087=1/31/2021}=6}
> ```

Please help me.

Comment: represent that `String,Date` as a `Pair` and then define a `compare` method for it, rest all would simplify

Comment: Could you explain how to pair? I didnt get that .

Comment: You're using a whole Map as a key to another map, but this key always has a single entry? Then why not make the map key a Map.Entry<String, Date> or define your own class (what Naman above suggested): class Pair with a string field and a Date field. Also, you should prefer java.time.LocalDate rather than the legacy and problematic java.util.Date.

Comment: Anyway, you can't have that sort of data in your question's example. You have a duplicate key {59087=1/31/2021} and maps cannot hold duplicate keys.

Answer (score -1):

You can not sort an HashMap. Use a SortedMap such as a TreeMap and a comparator.